# Ngnix : Forwarding url to AngularJS webapp

Tags: angularjs, nginx, reverse-proxy, haproxy, forwarding

With my AngularJS SPA webapp, I would like to use a Ngnix to forward url
from example :

```
   http://example.com
   http://example.com/#/user/login
   ...
```

to :

```
   http://example.com:8080/webappname
   http://example.com:8080/webappname/#/user/login
```

I tried this configuration :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/webappname;
    }
}
```

But it does not work.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a "/" at the end. Without a URL

```
http://example.com/#/user/login
```

is translated to

```
http://example.com:8080/webappname#/user/login
```

Here's the correct line:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/webappname/;
```